# Резка типа string на составляющие в массив

Tags: массивы, строки, c++

Как лучше порезать строку из чисел неопределенного размера, разделенных пробелом на массив чисел или строк? Строка представляет собой тип `std::string`, числа многозначные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант для чистого Си как с модификацией исходной строки (a'la strtok()), так и без нее не намного сложнее, особенно если выбросить проверки выделения памяти и воспользоваться уже готовой функцией "строительства" вектора.

```
// returns pointer to not delimiter char in str
static inline char *
skip_delim (const char *str,  const char *delim)
{
  int l = strspn(str, delim);

  return (char *) (str[l] ? str + l : 0);
}
```

Основная часть, для краткости проверка на память и realloc результата выброшены

```
// split string (char *) by delimiters (if mcopy == 0 then split "on place")
// returns size of NULL-terminated vector (like argv[] in main()) of  "substrings"
int
split_str (char *src, const char *delim, int mcopy, char ***res)
{
  char **pr = *res = 0, *p;
  int l, n = 0;

  while ((p = skip_delim(src, delim))) {
    src = p + (l = strcspn(p, delim));
    if (mcopy)
      p = strndup(p, l);
    av_addyna((char **)&pr, &n, (const char *)&p, sizeof(p));
    if (!mcopy)
      *src = 0;
  }

  *res = pr;
  return n;
}
```

Вот так вызываем для с копированием памяти (т.е. исходную строку не портим)

```
int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char **res, buf[1000];
  int n, i;

  while (fgets(buf, 1000, stdin)) {
    if ((n = spl_str(buf, " \t\n", 1, &res)) > 0) {
      printf("n = %d [%s]\n", n, buf);
      for (i = 0; res[i]; i++)
        puts(res[i]);
      free_mem(res, n, 1);
    } else if (n == -1)
      perror("split_str");
  }

}
```

Это функция для наращивания вектора-результата. Обратите внимание для выделения памяти ей достаточно только текущего количества элементов, помещенных в вектор (выделяемый размер нигде не хранится).

```
#define DYNALIM 1024

// add new item to dynamic array, returns array size or 0 if no memory
int
av_addyna (char **pa, int *pn, const char *arg, int itemsize)
{
  // 0 : 2+,  1 : 4+,  2 : 4,  3 : 8+,  4 : 8,  5 : 8,  6 : 8,  7 : 16+   ...
  int size, old, n = *pn;

  if (n < 0)
    n = 0;
  char *t = *pa;

  if (n < DYNALIM) {
    size = 1 << (32 - __builtin_clz(n + 1));
    old = n ? 1 << (32 - __builtin_clz(n)) : 1;
  } else {
    size = ((n + 1) & ~(DYNALIM - 1)) + DYNALIM;
    old = (n & ~(DYNALIM - 1)) + DYNALIM;
  }

  if (old != size )
    if (!(*pa = (char *)realloc(*pa, size * itemsize))) {
      *pa = t;
      return 0;
    }

  memcpy(*pa + n++ * itemsize, arg, itemsize);
  memset(*pa + n * itemsize, 0, itemsize);
  return *pn = n;
}
```

Это освобождение памяти после `split_str` (в Linux можно не проверять аргумент free() на 0).

```
int
free_mem (char **p, int n, int mcopy)
{
  if (p && mcopy) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      free(p[i]);
  }
  free(p);
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну что ж, давайте тряхнём стариной.

Варианты со `stringstream`'ом я бы не советовал в силу их неконфигурируемости: `stringstream` умеет резать лишь по пробелам, и заставить его считать пробелом другой символ [не так уж просто](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607650/276994). Кроме того, `stringstream` копирует лишний раз исходную строку, что, как вы понимаете, не прибавляет к производительности.

[Варианты с `boost`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_idp110108928.html) наверное лучше всего, но я их не буду рассматривать в силу их неспортивности: использовать готовое решение скучно.

Вариант с [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) рассматривать не буду, чтобы не вторгаться на территорию @avp. Скажу лишь, что он модифицирует исходную строку, что может быть или не быть проблемой, в зависимости от задачи.

Поэтому остаётся написать функцию самому. Поехали!

```
using namespace std; // я ленивый, да
void split(const string& source, const string& delimiters, vector<string>& result)
{
    // поддерживаем следующий инвариант: символ по индексу есть начало нового куска
    // пропускаем разделители в начале
    auto start = source.find_first_not_of(delimiters);
    while (start != string::npos)
    {
        // ищем следующий конец куска
        auto end = source.find_first_of(delimiters, start);
        // и его длину
        auto len = end == string::npos ? string::npos : (end - start);
        // запоминаем найденный кусок
        result.push_back(source.substr(start, len));
        // и переходим к следующему
        start = source.find_first_not_of(delimiters, end);
    }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/NZNZSQ

Answer (score 0):

google c++ explode string / google c++ split string into string vector -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967010 https://stackoverflow.com/a/236976 и зубодробительная (сам я с с++ не работал никогда, может, это и лафа) https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607650

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с итераторами:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string strInts = "11 -2 -8 4 55";           
    std::istringstream streamInts(strInts);
    std::istream_iterator<int> dataBegin(streamInts);
    std::istream_iterator<int> dataEnd;
    std::vector<int> vectorInts(dataBegin, dataEnd); // Вывод {11, -2, -8, 4, 55}
}
```